# Add entries to an array inside a loop

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I am trying to update an array in a linux tcsh script. The script uses a while loop, and I want to add elements to the array every time the loop iterates. Is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/bin/tcsh
clear
set x = 1
while ($x <= 10)

echo "Enter a number..."
set number = $<
set numbers = ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
set numbers[$x] = $number
echo "The number you entered was $number."

if ($number < 0) then
        exit 1
else if (0 <= $number && $number < 100) then
        echo "The number is out of range. Please enter another number."
endif
echo $numbers[1-]
#echo $number[10]
@ x++
end
@ y = $number[1]
echo $y
```

Comment: I don't know tcsh so I can't really help here but you realize your script doesn't work right? You are resetting the array at each iteration so it only ever keeps one non=0 number at a time.